# Suggested actions applying background svg image not displaying sometimes

Tags: botframework

I am using bot framework to create chatbot application. In work flow I am using suggested actions the button with thumbs up and thumbs down i have replaced with background svg image but the image is sometimes displaying and sometimes not displaying in web browser.

```
 <div class="wc-suggested-actions"><div>

.wc-suggested-actions .wc-hscroll > ul > li:nth-child(2) button {
            background-image: url(/Content/Images/L-ThumbsDown.svg) !important;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .wc-suggested-actions .wc-hscroll > ul > li:first-child button {
            background-image: url(/Content/Images/L-ThumbsUp.svg) !important;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

Comment: WHen it is not displayed, what is it showing instead?

Comment: sometimes it is showing the images and sometimes showing blank instead of image getting below warning in console.    Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response in botchat.css